# Update Database Function

Tags: php, model-view-controller

I'm writing an update database function in MVC architecture, but I can't seem to get the function to work.

model.php

```
public function update($table, $fields, $args, $id) {
        # update DB implementation
        $argString = implode('\',\'', $args);
        $fieldString = implode(',', $fields);
        $sql = "UPDATE $table SET ($fieldString) VALUES('$argString') WHERE id=$id";
        return($this->connection->query($sql));
    }
```

controller.php

```
private function updatePlayer($fields, $values) {
    return $this->model->update('Players', $fields, $values);
}
```

POST statement in controller

```
elseif($server['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
    # if the ID_FIELD is empty it’s a create request
        if(empty($post['id'])) {
            # replace FIELD NAMES as per your field names in the database
            echo $this->addPlayer(['Player_Name', 'Age', 'City', 'Country', 'Gender', 'Handedness', 'Broom', 'Position', 'Team', 'Favorite_Color', 'Headshot'], [$post['Player_Name'], $post['Age'], $post['City'], $post['Country'], $post['Gender'], $post['Handedness'], $post['Broom'], $post['Position'], $post['Team'], $post['Favorite_Color'], $post['Headshot']]);
        }

        # if the ID_FIELD is not empty then it’s an update request
        else { 
            echo $this->updatePlayer(['Player_Name', 'Age', 'City', 'Country', 'Gender', 'Handedness', 'Broom', 'Position', 'Team', 'Favorite_Color', 'Headshot'], [$post['Player_Name'], $post['Age'], $post['City'], $post['Country'], $post['Gender'], $post['Handedness'], $post['Broom'], $post['Position'], $post['Team'], $post['Favorite_Color'], $post['Headshot']]);
        }
    }
```

Any thoughts or insight is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Your query doesn't seem to be valid UPDATE syntax

Comment: update() used $id  and updatePlayer() does not pass the $id value...so update query will not work.

Comment: When I add the $id to the update function, I still create new records and not update the current records.